# Patching the KRACK WPA2 Vulnerability in Airport wireless routers

Tags: security, software-update, airport

Will Apple provide firmware updates for Airport routers to patch the [KRACK](https://github.com/vanhoefm/krackattacks/blob/gh-pages/index.html) vulnerability?

Apple's [abandonement](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-11-21/apple-said-to-abandon-development-of-wireless-routers-ivs0ssec) of the Airport product line has me worried.

Comment: Nobody can answer if Apple **will** do something; that's for Apple to say.  However, it's feasible to answer the question  *has something has been done?*  See this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/302370/119271) for reference

Comment: According to Mathy Vanhoef who discovered the vulnerability, it is mainly client devices (phones and computers, not routers) that need a patch. See the section titled "What if there are no security updates for my router?" on [https://www.krackattacks.com/](https://www.krackattacks.com/).

Comment: @Allan: A negative factual answer is certainly possible. Apple could release a statement that they will not provide patches for certain products because they consider them to have reached end of life.

Comment: @ChristianDavid - that's entirely true; I took that position since Apple is notoriously tight lipped about security so until you actually have something, it's speculation at best especially given the forward looking tone of the question.  That said...my advice has always to avoid "consumer grade stuff" (Linksys, Netgear, Asus, and yes, even Apple) and get more "enterprise grade" networking.  I used to swap things out on a 12-18 month cycle due to failure.  Now, I am getting at minimum 3 years on my routers and WAPs

Comment: https://www.imore.com/krack-wpa2-wi-fi-exploit-already-fixed-ios-macos-tvos-watchos-betas according to press the airport line is not affected. As this appears to be mostly a client-side attack, I'd say there is not much to be done with the router itself in any case.