# Mac OS 10.10 Yosemite: Where do I get the patch to fix the Meltdown exploit?

Tags: macos, security, software-update

All I found were articles on patch availability for El Capitan, Sierra, and High Sierra. Where do I get a patch to fix the Meltdown exploit? (type that into Google if you don't know what that is, it's been all the buzz in tech news last week)

Bonus points if there's also a patch to minimize the risk of the Spectre exploit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no patches for Yosemite as Yosemite is no longer supported. You will need to upgrade to a newer macOS. You can find details of patches for Meltdown and Spectre released by Apple in the question [Is there a Meltdown vulnerability fix already available for macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/311197/37797).