# Is Spectre and Meltdown Patched on OS X 10.10?

Tags: macos, malware

I have not yet had an update since the spectre and meltdown vulnerabilities came out...

This leads me to believe they have not patched spectre/meltdown on anything below High Sierra...

I have hardware that does not support drivers past 10.10, therefore I cannot upgrade without paying $1000 in musical equipment; plus, everytime I upgrade, my computer slows down significantly and I don't want to deal with the hassle.

Comment: @klanomath Says nothing about anything below **High Sierra**

Comment: You can see a list of all Apple security updates here. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201222 Yosemite last received a security update in July 2017.

Comment: [Mac OS 10.10 Yosemite: Where do I get the patch to fix the Meltdown exploit?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311746/mac-os-10-10-yosemite-where-do-i-get-the-patch-to-fix-the-meltdown-exploit?noredirect=1&lq=1): "There are no patches for Yosemite as Yosemite is no longer supported"

Comment: @klanomath ok. that answered my question. Thank you sir/madam