# Has Apple released updates for its Airport base stations to protect against the KRACK vulnerability?

Tags: network, wifi, security, airport

Regarding the vulnerability in [WPA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access) known as [KRACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KRACK), has Apple released firmware updates yet for the Apple-branded [AirPort Base Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPort#AirPort_routers) devices?

Comment: While the question is not exactly a dupe (iOS versus AirPort), the premise is and the answer is the same.  Possible duplicate of [Has the WiFi KRACK vulnerability been patched for iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302360/has-the-wifi-krack-vulnerability-been-patched-for-ios)

Comment: @Allan Actually the technical issues for KRACK may differ by access point versus client-side, according to early reports. Even issues regarding iOS versus macOS may differ according to some reports. One of the keys to success for a Stack Exchange is narrow specificity. Makes sense to me to keep theses platforms distinct regarding KRACK, to avoid confusing intertwining threads of coverage in the Answers.

Comment: The question, as written, is "if" Apple has released a fix, not what the differences are in the security fix.  The answer provided addresses the availability of security fixes for **all**  Apple products which answers the question.  That said - there really is no distinction between AP and client - the vulnerability is the same.

Comment: @Allan No, access points at at a different risk than clients. As described on the [KrackAttacks](https://www.krackattacks.com) website that discloses the vulnerability, some access points may not need any update. Just because Apple may have clients that need patching does not mean their access points will need patching. As much as you may want a simple one-size-fits-all answer to the KRACK problem, there is not one. As for your mention of an Answer addressing “**all** Apple products”, please link. I do not see AirPort Base Stations covered.

Comment: @Allan It's not really a duplicate. Routers seem only affected if they use/provide special protocols (802.11r/802.1s). The real duplicate would be: [Patching the KRACK WPA2 Vulnerability in Airport wireless routers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302354/patching-the-krack-wpa2-vulnerability-in-airport-wireless-routers). This linked question has another flaw though.

Comment: @klanomath Your proposed duplicate is not a duplicate, as that one calls for speculation about Apple's future behavior (and so was correctly closed as off-topic) while my Question here asks for factual history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present there are no updates for the AirPort product line.  Apple is notoriously tight lipped about security issues.

> For our customers' protection, Apple doesn't disclose, discuss, or
>   confirm security issues until an investigation has occurred and
>   patches or releases are available. Recent releases are listed on the
>   [Apple security updates](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201222) page.

If/when Apple releases an update that's security related, it will be listed on the [Apple Security Updates page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201222).  You can get more info about this from the question/answer "[Has the WiFi KRACK vulnerability been patched for iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302360/has-the-wifi-krack-vulnerability-been-patched-for-ios)"

Additionally, you can check the [AirPort Firmware Update page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201519) which will provide directions, links, and details on the updates and how to apply them.

At the time of this post, the most recent update were (dated Dec. 20, 2016)

- 7.7.8 for the AirPort Extreme and Time Capsule 802.11ac products
- 7.6.8 for the Airport Extreme, Express and Time Capsule 802.11n products

Therefore, at the time of this answer/post there have been no updates to address the KRACK vulnerability.